# Unix timestamp: everywhere the same?

Tags: unix-timestamp

If I request some Unix timestamps at the same time, in any system, programming language, anywhere on the world (on universe), will they always be the same? Or is it possible that values differ?

As a precondition I assume that each system has to have their time configured correctly. Additional question: nowadays, can I assume devices with an internet connection have the correct time?

So, how reliable is the usage of the Unix timestamp? E.g. if I'd like so set an alert for different users on the world at a certain time and I broadcast just the timestamp, can I assume that the alerts happen in the same second?

(Journeys with speed of light should be disregarded here, I guess.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unix timestamps are the number of seconds elapsed since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC so if the system time is set correctly it should be equal everywhere.